# Cannot write on input field using getFieldDecorator

Tags: reactjs, forms, ecmascript-6, antd

I have a simple form with one input field.
The form is diplayed correctly but it's not possible to write a value on it.
The field it's enabled but it's not possible to write any value.

Removing getFieldDecorator all works fine and the field can be write.

How can I use getFieldDecorator to manage this input?

```
import React from 'react'
import Page from 'components/LayoutComponents/Page'
import { withRouter, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Form, Input, } from 'antd'
import { injectIntl } from 'react-intl'

class TestPageForm extends React.Component {

    state = {
        name: ""
    }

    constructor( props ) {
        super( props )
        this.handleNameChange = this.handleNameChange.bind( this )
    }

    handleNameChange( e ) {
        this.setState( {
            ...this.state,
            name: e.target.value
        } )
     }

    render() {
        const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form

        return (
            <Page>
                <Form>
                    <Form.Item>
                        {getFieldDecorator( 'name', {
                            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your Name!' }],
                        } )(
                             <Input
                            onChange={this.handleNameChange} placeholder="Name"
                        />,
                        )}
                     </Form.Item>
                 </Form>
             </Page>
        )
    }
}
const TestPage = Form.create()( TestPageForm )
export default withRouter( injectIntl( TestPage ) )
```

Comment: Your code works fine, reproduce the problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/q-57078521-idpix

Comment: Thank you, you are right. There was an error mounting the component.